# Is Responsive Web Design the way to go?

Tags: mobile, responsive-design

I am working on making a website and I have been looking into making a mobile website. I just recently learned about responsive web design and have been looking into it.
http://designmodo.com/responsive-design-vs-mobile-website-vs-app/
http://www.smartz.com/web-development/mobile/mobile-vs-responsive-design/
I am interested in this and it looks like it might be a good solution. My question is if it is a professional way to go mobile?
It looks like it is very flexable and I do like the idea of not having any redirects, but I just am wondering if it is a good solution.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: There are many more factors that you need to consider when choosing the right tool for a job, and there are many more tools than a responsive design. For example, mgwt allows you to write code once, while the compiler creates highly optimized versions of your code for different form factors and different operating systems - no media queries necessary. And even responsive design can be done in different ways, using, for example, a box layout model (again, no media queries).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It totally depends on what you're website does and how you expect your users to interact with it.

If the website is mainly presenting text (e.g. a blog) and/or is mainly intended to be used on a desktop/laptop, then RD is sufficient.
If, on the other hand, you have many user interactions (through controls) and/or you expect your website to be used heavily in a mobile context, then you will be better off with an app.

Generally, RD is slower, you can have display/rendering issues because of different mobile browsers, and RD is not as ergonomic as a native app. On the other hand, it's much cheaper, and if mobile access is only a side aspect of the website, then RD might be the way to go.

Comment: So responsive web design is slow too? Is it slower than a redirect? Also, I am mostly looking for a mobile website, Is an app better? I don't know a lot, I just found responsive web design and it looked cool.

Comment: With slow I mean that you have to access a website, which is sometimes problematic with mobile devices (environmental issues, data plans, available connection/bandwith etc.). The website is not generally slower as such. On the other side, developing mobile apps (remember that you usually have to target at least two platforms, using two different programming languages) is quite cost intensive, so it does not pay in many cases. As I said, it totally depends on the concrete project and its business goals.

Comment: I guess my question is should I pursue responsive web design

Comment: Definitely. It's a must-have in a web developer's toolbelt. It's just that it might not be applicable in each and every case.

Comment: Sure. I did not suspect that :-)

Comment: @ThomasWeller: Why do you think that responsive design is slower? If you use box layout model (and no Javascript resizing anywhere), the browser will layout the page natively, so there will be no performance penalty compared to native apps.

Comment: @Andrei Volgin I mean. Browsing is generally much slower than using an app. Furthermore, you have many connection/environmental issues when targeting mobile devices.

Comment: Really?! Browser-based apps may have exactly the same UI and behavior as native apps.